# How do you pick out rows from an array based on a specific value in a column?

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have an array of data.  For simplicity, let's call it a 4 x 3 matrix.  Let's say I want to find a data point in column 2 that has a value of 5.  Then, I want to take all rows that contains the value of 5 in column 2 and place it in its own array.  My data is much larger than the one displayed below, so I don't want to go through by eye and look at every line of data and identify all the 5's.

```
  % My idea of the code:

  data = [1 2 3 4; 5 5 5 6; 6 4 5 6]

  if data(:,2) == 5

  % This is the part I can't figure out

  end
```

Let's call the finaldata the array in which the data with 5's will be stored.  How do I do this?

Comment: Thank you!  No if-statement is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?s_tid=doc_12b):

```
all_fives_rows = data(data(:, 2) == 5, :)
```

Comment: I think you mean `data(data(:, 2) == 5, :);` - the OP asked for all *rows* with a 5 in column 2 :-) But yes, I agree logical indexing is the right way to solve this problem (+1). For anyone else reading, this is definitely a better solution than using `find` (as suggested in the other answer).

Comment: @ColinTBowers, oooops, yes, of course, that was what I meant - thanks. Fixed.

Comment: data(find (data(:,2)==5),:) does the same thing isn`t?

Comment: Besides, find is optimized to search for those items... [Reference for that statement](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/102545)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) Function to search that value, and give the coords back (it might be a vector) to retrieve the rows:

```
data(find (data(:,2)==5),:)
```

Why not using logical indexing: [Performance](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/102545)